# how to translate curl -X post into java

Tags: java, rest, curl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to translate a curl command into Java (using Apache HttpClient 4.x):

```
export APPLICATION_ID=SOME_ID
export REST_API_KEY=SOME_KEY

curl -i -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: image/png" \
  --data-binary @/Users/thomas/Desktop/greep-small.png \
  https://api.parse.com/1/files/greep.png
```

but I get the following error: {"error":"unauthorized"}.

This is what my java code looks like:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 80, "http"); 
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()), 
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://api.parse.com/1/files/greep.png");

System.out.println("executing request:\n" + httpPost.getRequestLine());

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Example-Application-Id", "SOME_ID"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Example-REST-API-Key", "SOME_KEY"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "image/png"));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (responseEntity != null) {
    System.out.println("Response content length: " 
            + responseEntity.getContentLength());
}
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity));
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

How can I translate a curl line that starts with -H and a curl line that starts with "--data-binary"? Whats the java equivalent for -d?

```
  -d '{ "name":"Andrew", "picture": { "name": "greep.png", "__type": "File" } }' \
```

Any hint is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -i -X POST..."); Couldn't resist, sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

The headers don't match. The `curl` command is using `X-Parse-Application-Id` and `X-Parse-REST-API-Key` whereas the Java code is using `Example-Application-Id` and `Example-REST-API-Key`. I imagine you'd want those to match. Plus, you are setting them as the `POST` body of the request instead of as HTTP headers. You need to use one of the [`setHeader`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) methods on `httpPost` instead. I would also recommend not explicitly setting `Content-Type` in such a manner. The content type is usually provided as part of the `HttpEntity` being posted.

To post the image content using HttpClient in Java, you would need to use a [`FileEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) that references the path of the file (`/Users/thomas/Desktop/greep-small.png` in your example). Right now you are posting the header values as name value pairs as I mentioned before.

Implementing `curl -d` would require doing something like passing a [`StringEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html) to `httpPost.setEntity()` using the value you want to send.

Finally, the Java code is using some credentials that I don't see going on at all in the `curl` command.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. I'll try your hints and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks @laz, you made my day. I was using MultipartEntity, but to simulate --data-binary behavior, we really need to use FileEntity. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @laz Same here FileEntity is the key to replicating --data-binary