# Runtime Exec seems to be ignoring apostrophes

Tags: java, command

A simple example is trying to cd to a directory that has more than two words. When I run the below code, I don't get the expected error: `/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: /Directory With Two Words: No such file or directory`, but this error: `/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: '/Directory: No such file or directory`. So it seems like it is ignoring the apostrophes and just looking for a directory called "Directory".

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test
{
     public static void main(String []args)
     {
        try 
        {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd '/Directory With Two Words'");
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            // read any errors from the attempted command
            System.out.println("Error:");
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the [`exec(String[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) method it's far safer. So this should work without quotes or apostrophes:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cd", "/Directory With Two Words"});
```

Also worth taking a look at the excellent article at JavaWorld [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).